# amazon cloudsearch structured query prefix not returning the same results as simple query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm searching for the prefix q=red bul* using the simple query parser and I get results however when I change it to use structured query and do (prefix 'red bul') I get no results.

Am I missing something and can anyone else replicate this issue?

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31970512/3305742).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have better results, when using the structured parser, if I include the final word as either a whole word or as a prefix. For example:

```
Query: "(and title_en:'red' (or title_en:'bul' (prefix field='title_en' 'bul')))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the field when using the prefix operator, eg

`(prefix field=foo 'red bul')`.

See
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-prefixes

Comment: I am also able to reproduce the problem at hand and this makes no difference. From the AWS docs: **If you do not specify the field you want to search when using the structured query parser, all statically configured text and text-array fields are searched.** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html#structured-search-syntax

Comment: The next line is *Dynamic fields and literal fields are not searched by default*. We don't know whether `foo` is literal. It sounds like it might be

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do

```
(prefix 'bul') 'red'
```