# How to do wildcard search using structured prefix operator with AWS CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, search-engine, amazon-cloudsearch

I've currently migrating to the 2013 Cloudsearch API (from the 2011 API). Previously, I had been using a wildcard prefix with my searches, like this:

```
bq=(and 'first secon*')
```

My queries sometimes include facet options, which is why I use the boolean query syntax and not the simple version.

I've created a new cloudsearch instance using the 2013 engine and indexed it. The `bq` parameter is gone now, so I have to use the `q` parameter with the `q.parser=structured` parameter to get the same functionality. When I query with something like this:

```
q.parser=simple&q=first secon*
```

...I get back a load of results. But when I query with this:

```
q.parser=structured&q=(prefix 'first secon')
```

...I get no hits. I don't get an error, just no results found. Am I doing something wrong?

I've just realized that if I do a prefix search for the word `firs` with the 2013 API, the prefix search seems to be working. But if I have any more than a single term in the query e.g. `first secon` then the prefix search does not work. So how is this accomplished using the structured prefix operator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the prefix operator for each separate query term, eg:

`q=(or (prefix 'firs') (prefix 'secon'))&q.parser=structured`

Comment: I noticed that the prefix operator doesn't work for me if the prefix term is complete e.g. if I prefix search for `secon`, that will get me results for `second`, but if I prefix search for `second`, then I don't get those same results. I thought the docs said that the prefix operator matches that term with zero or more characters after it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm... I think either stemming is affecting this or prefix search does not return full matches. There's not a lot of visibility into what algorithmic stemming is doing though. You could try adding a term to your query without the prefix operator and ORing it with what you have above, eg (or (prefix 'second') second'). Sorry if the syntax isn't exactly right--I'm on my phone or I'd test it out

Comment: That's OK, I've been able to achieve the effect I want with something like: 
`q=(and (term 'first') (or (term 'secon') (prefix 'secon')) )`
I reckon this is what you were getting at.

Answer (score 0):

If someones looking for JS code to solve this issue. What you need to do is split the user input on space, and store them in an array. The join the words you want to query back together with pipes.

```
      var params = {
        query: ''
      };

      //Check for spaces
      let words = query.split(' ');
      let chunks = [];
      words.forEach(word => {
        chunks.push(`${word}* | ${word}`);
      })

      params.query = chunks.join(' | ');

      cloudsearch.search(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q.parser=structured&q=(and (phrase 'first') (prefix 'secon'))
```

you can try like this.
**phrase**, confirm that must have ***first***. and **prefix** with ***secon****